# Form change event on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dom-events

I really cant understand what is the problem here. I want when checkbox in the form is clicked to get to the closest "h2" and to get its text.

> **HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="productFilterForm">
  <h2 class="attribute-name">Brands</h2>
  <div class="option">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Royal Canin" value="163">Royal Canin
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Brit" value="164">Brit
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Purina Pro Plan" value="165">Purina Pro Plan
      </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

> **JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#productFilterForm').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function () {
    let text = $(this).closest("h2").html(); <---- UNDEFINED
    //let text = $(this).find("h2").html(); <---- UNDEFINED
    console.log(text);
   }
});
```

I tried many things and methods, just cant find any element from the "input" up to the DOM tree.

Comment: H2 is not a parent... closest looks at parents

Comment: As i said i tried many things, also find and other methods.

Comment: $(this).closest("form").find("h2")

Comment: @epascarello - With that if i have another block with "h2" and options below, if i click on the new options checkbox it will again return the first "h2". Isnt there are way just to start from the input UP and to stop on the first "h2"

Comment: why don't you render all options with a class name say title of the h2 you want to find?

Comment: @Stoyo Than you should have shown that.... We can not guess that you have more than one. If you can wrap it in a div, it would be simple. But you can look for the parent option div, and look at the prev siblings until you find the h2...

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('#productFilterForm').on('change', function () {
let text = $(this).find("h2").html();
console.log(text);   
})
```

Comment: Ahh, seems like now the other problem is if there is another block with "h2" and options below, if i click on the new checkboxes it returns again the first "h2" not the new one. - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPMPPe?editors=1111

Comment: you can specify a class for each h2 and select the elements by a class and get the value

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#productFilterForm input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
      let text = $(this).closest('div.option').prevAll('h2.attribute-name').html();
      console.log(text);
   }
});
```